# is it possible to get python purple running either in cygwin or on a linux that isn't debian?

Tags: python, linux, cygwin, debhelper

python purple says it needs dbms and debhelper in order to run, but I don't run debian. Is there a way to get this running on a different linux? or in cygwin?

Comment: Have you tried building it and skipping the last step (i.e. don't generate debian packages)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both cdbs and debhelper are only needed if you are trying to build a debian package. Just do a regular `python setup.py build`, and it should work fine (assuming you have the other prerequisites available).