# If a python module says its dependent on debhelper and cdbs is there no way to get it to run on a nondebian linux?

Tags: python, linux, debian, cdbs

I want to try python purple but I don't have debian. Is there a way to get it to run on either windows or a different linux?

Comment: This is the same question as your question here i guess: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224726/is-it-possible-to-get-python-purple-running-either-in-cygwin-or-on-a-linux-that-i Please do not doublepost...

Comment: My bad, I thought maybe if I readdressed the question using different tags it might catch the attention of a more relevant audience. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @Ryan: You could respond to the question I left on your previous question...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose compiling from source (if availiable) or looking for dbhelper and cbds install files for your distribution

Comment: Seems an interesting idea